# How can I fully merge two tree objects with spread operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to merge two tree objects into one with the spread operator, but I am not getting the correct merged result.
How can I fully merge two tree objects with spread operator ?

```js
const tree1 = [{
  comments: [{
    text: "This a comment for case law 84",
    id: "84"
  }, {
    text: "This a comment for case law 89",
    id: "89"
  }],
  children: [{
    comments: [{
      text: "This a comment for case law 70",
      id: "70"
    }],
    children: [{
      comments: [{
        text: "This a comment for case law 83",
        id: "83"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];

const tree2 = [{
  comments: [{
    text: "This a comment for case law 184",
    id: "184"
  }],
  children: [{
    comments: [{
      text: "This a comment for case law 170",
      id: "170"
    }],
    children: [{
      comments: [{
        text: "This a comment for case law 183",
        id: "183"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];

const mergedTrees = [{ ...tree2, ...tree1 }];
console.log("mergedTrees", mergedTrees);
```

The problem is while merging the properties with the same key get overwritten. The rightmost property has the highest precedence.
What I need to get this kind of merge? :

```
{
  "0": {
    "comments": [
      {
        "text": "This a comment for case law 84",
        "id": "84"
      },
      {
        "text": "This a comment for case law 89",
        "id": "89"
      },
      {
        "text": "This a comment for case law 184",
        "id": "184"
      }
    ],
    "children": [
      {
        "comments": [
          {
            "text": "This a comment for case law 70",
            "id": "70"
          },
          {
            "text": "This a comment for case law 170",
            "id": "170"
          }
        ],
        "children": [
          {
            "comments": [
              {
                "text": "This a comment for case law 83",
                "id": "83"
              },
              {
                "text": "This a comment for case law 183",
                "id": "183"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

if it's not possible with the spread operator and there is another way to make it, please let me know.

adding a link for tries: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fffika?file=index.ts

Comment: You don't want the object with id "89" in the end result?

Comment: @Christian sorry for that, yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merge the arrays index-wise and take the same approach for nested children.

```js
const
    merge = (a, b) => [a, b].reduce((r, array) => {
        array.forEach(({ children, ...o }, i) => {
            r[i] ??= { };
            Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (r[i][k] ??= []).push(...v));
            if (children) r[i].children = merge(r[i].children || [], children);
        });
        return r;
    }, []),
    tree1 = [{ comments: [{ text: "This a comment for case law 84", id: "84" }], news: [{ text: "This news 1 ", id: "1" }], children: [{ comments: [{ text: "This a comment for case law 70", id: "70" }], news: [{ text: "This news 2 ", id: "2" }, { text: "This news 3 ", id: "3" }], children: [{ comments: [{ text: "This a comment for case law 83", id: "83" }], news: [{ text: "This news 4 ", id: "4" }] }] }] }],
    tree2 = [{ comments: [{ text: "This a comment for case law 184", id: "184" }], news: [{ text: "This news 12 ", id: "12" }, { text: "This news 13 ", id: "13" }], children: [{ comments: [{ text: "This a comment for case law 170", id: "170" }], news: [{ text: "This news 22 ", id: "22" }, { text: "This news 33", id: "33" }], children: [{ comments: [{ text: "This a comment for case law 183", id: "183" }], news: [{ text: "This news 122 ", id: "122" }, { text: "This news 133 ", id: "133" }] }] }] }]
    result = merge(tree1, tree2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am trying it to my component ts and I am getting 
error TS1109: Expression expected where the ??= is and error TS1005: ':' expected at the end of same line. Got any idea of how to bypass that?

Comment: @wilbi, you could replace `r[i] ??= { comments: [] };` with `r[i] = r[i] || { comments: [] };`.

Comment: That worked. In my case I have more array nodes and not only comments. Can you please add in your example another one for ex: news: [] ?

Comment: do you have an example of it?

Comment: Thanks. I just changed this one, I hope it helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fffika?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks a lot Nina, now it's dynamic ! <3

Comment: getting a [root] CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object and I guess it's because there are also array of objects and objects in my json. And I had to change both nullish assignment ??= based on your previous comment.

Comment: should i change something?

Comment: I really don't know. I was thinking a solution to this could work: shorturl.at/ovBX7 but even in this case it's the "Last Write Wins" rule. I am trying to push the child node specific nodes to the one on the root but they are keep getting ovewritten. :(

Comment: if you don't know, how should i know? the above respect all data and never overwerites something.

Comment: That's true, based on the provided data it works as expected that's why I've marked it as solved. I will keep looking for a solution when the JSON contains multiple array of objects. Again, thanks for you help!